# Ошибка Segmentation fault

Tags: c++

Вылетает в этой фукции:

```
float Neuron::Axon::getSignal() const
{
    return 1 / (1 + exp(ownerNeuron->sum_function()));
}
```

Функция вызывается из:

```
float get_axon_value() const {return axon.getSignal(); }
```

Это функция из

```
vector<float> Neural_network::test(const vector<float> &in)
{
    set_inputs(in);
    vector<float> out(outNeurons.size());
    for (int i{0}; i < outNeurons.size(); i++)
        out[i] = outNeurons[i].get_axon_value();

    return out;
}
```

Это точка входа:

```
Neural_network neuralNetwork;
neuralNetwork.add_input_neuron(Neural_network::Input_neuron());
neuralNetwork.add_out_neuron(Neuron(
        std::vector<Neuron::Dendrite>{Neuron::Dendrite(
                1,
                neuralNetwork.get_input_neuron_ref(0).get_axon_ref()
        )}
));

std::cout << neuralNetwork.test(std::vector<float>{1})[0];
```

Типы:

```
/* Axon is the output part of the neuron. Dentrits gets value of neuron from it's Axon.*/
class Axon{
public:
    float getSignal() const;//Activation function
    Neuron *ownerNeuron;
};

/* Dendrite is an input part of neuron. It has weight. It gets value from axon of neron from previous layer.*/
class Dendrite{
public:
    float weight;
    Axon *inputAkson;

    Dendrite(float weight, Axon inAxon) : weight{weight}, inputAkson{&inAxon} {}
};

Neuron::Neuron() : axon()
{
    axon.ownerNeuron = this;
    dendrite.clear();
}

Neuron::Neuron(const vector<Dendrite>& dendrites) : Neuron()
{
    for(Dendrite den : dendrites)
        dendrite.emplace_back(den);
}


class Input_neuron : public Neuron{
    public:

        float sum_function(){
            return value;
        }

        void set_value(float v) { value = v; }

    private:
        float value;
    };
```

Остальные функции:

```
void Neural_network::add_input_neuron(const Neural_network::Input_neuron& inputNeuron) {
    inNeurons.emplace_back(inputNeuron);
}

void Neural_network::add_out_neuron(const Neuron& neuron) {
    outNeurons.emplace_back(neuron);
}

Neural_network::Input_neuron &Neural_network::get_input_neuron_ref(int ind) {
    if (ind < 0 || ind >= inNeurons.size())
        throw runtime_error("Neural_network::get_input_neuron_ref(): out of input neurons");
    return inNeurons[ind];
}

Axon& get_axon_ref() { return axon; }
```

Comment: Проходите отладчиком. Другого варианта не вижу - трассировать в уме какие-то куски кода, без конкретных данных - вряд ли кто-то возьмется.

Comment: Это и делаю сейчас. Подумал просто, может в коде ошибки какие супер очивидные, которые я не вижу.

Answer (score 3):

Нарушение Правила Трех.

Согласно вашей задумке, как я ее понял, указатель `ownerNeuron` содержащийся в поле `Neuron::axon`, должен в свою очередь указывать на сам `Neuron`, который содержит это поле `axon`. То есть каждый объект `Neuron` содержит внутри указатель на самого себя. Это значит, что каждый раз, когда происходит копирование объекта типа `Neuron`, необходимо исправлять указатель `axon.ownerNeuron` в полученной копии.

У вашего класса `Neuron` нет правильного конструктора копирования и копирующего оператора присваивания. В результате всякий раз, когда копируется объект типа `Neuron`, содержащееся в нем поле `axon` сохраняет прежнее значение указателя `axon.ownerNeuron`. Этот указатель запросто может "протухнуть" (и "протухает"), если оригинальный `Neuron` будет уничтожен. Позже, при обращении через такой висящий указатель вы получаете segfault. (И даже если оригинальный `Neuron` не будет уничтожен, все равно `axon.ownerNeuron` в копии будет указывать на неправльный экземпляр `Neuron`).

Чтобы исправить проблему, вам придется соблюсти Правило Трех (или Пяти): написать конструктор копирования (и/или перемещения) для `Neuron` и написать копирующий (и/или перемещающий) оператор присваивания для `Neuron`, который будет правильно выставлять `axon.ownerNeuron` в копии.